# How many Tables can you put in a Tableau Data Extract (.tde file)?

Tags: python, tableau-api

I'm using the Python SDK to create a TDE file. I want to add multiple tables to the TDE file. So I tried doing that but I got a duplicate name error:

> dataextract.Exceptions.TableauException: TableauException (303):
>   duplicate table name

No problemo, I changed the name so that it counts up with each table I create:

```
tde_table = tde_file.addTable('Extract'+str(i), table_definition)
```

but then I get a new and exciting error:

> dataextract.Exceptions.TableauException: TableauException (303): table
>   name must be "Extract"

Perhaps Extracts created through the SDK cannot have more than one table per extract? If every table in an extract needs to be named the same thing, but they can't have duplicate names... I'm confused. Can someone help clarify this for me?

Here's all the relevant code I think, but I don't know if it'll be much help:

```
...
for i, df in enumerate(dataframes):
    table_return_list   = _form_table_definition(df,data_types,read_out)
    table_definition    = table_return_list[0]
    header_type_map     = table_return_list[1]

    #use the table definition to create the table and row
    tde_table   = tde_file.addTable('Extract'+str(i), table_definition)
    tde_row     = tde.Row(table_definition)
    ...
```

Comment: An extract is a cached query result. The original query could pull information from multiple tables, but the query result is a single table by definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that it's impossible at the present moment to add more than one table to a data extract through the Python SDK. I don't know otherwise.

http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/sdk/en-us/SDK/Python/html/classtableausdk_1_1_extract_1_1_extract.html#a70b49a6eca6f1724bd89a928c73ecc8c

From their SDK documentation:

> def tableausdk.Extract.Extract.addTable   (       self,   name, 
>     tableDefinition  )       Adds a table to the extract.
>
> Parameters
>
> self  The object pointer.
>
> name  The name of the table to add.
>   **Currently, this method can only add a table named "Extract".**